# Different Browser Same Session in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

When I login into a rails application using chrome browser, then I login into another account using Firefox browser. At the same time I refresh the chrome browser, 2nd login details shown in the chrome browser. How can I solve this problem?
And I'm using (devise_security_extension) gem.

Comment: You are not giving enough information, but if you are experiencing this, it means that you are sharing the session data across your application.

Comment: Thanks for response. Please find my updated post.